# Displaying collection (ALL) fields of same content type

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

Here is the code , it's getting me only the last field I posted , whereas I want to display ALL the fields !

```
                        if (!empty($node)) :
                            //$fieldImage = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_image_slider');
                            print var_dump($node);
                            foreach ($node->field_image_slider['und'] as $item) {
                                $val=$item['uri'];
                                print '<div class="item"><figure><img src="' .file_create_url($val). '" /></figure><h3 class="orange">Hi</h3></div>';
                            } 
                        endif;
```

Till now I've spent 2 days searching for a solution , but I did'nt found ..
Any help would be extremely appreciated !

Comment: You don't need `field_get_items` the way you are accessing the field values in your `foreach`. Also `count($node)` should be 1 in this case. If you do `var_dump($node->field_image_slider)`  do you see multiple images?

Comment: how can I use this function ? I mean var_dump .
@ScottAnderson

Comment: Remove `print count($node); //Outputing only 1` and paste in `var_dump($node->field_image_slider)`

Comment: I did that, nothing appears

Comment: sorry make it `print var_dump($node->field_image_slider);`

Comment: Try `print var_dump($node);`

Comment: Also null ;
the code becomes like this : 
print var_dump($node);
        foreach ($node->field_image_slider['und'] as $item) {
         $val=$item['uri'];
         print '<div class="item"><figure><img src="' .file_create_url($val). '" /></figure><h3 class="orange">Hi</h3></div>';
        } 


But NULL !

Comment: I don't see how $node can be NULL when you're inside the `if (!empty($node))`

Comment: I edited the code check it ; there is nothing to display at all now

Comment: So $node is NULL. Where is this code appearing? A template file?

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
if (arg(0) == 'node') {
  $node = node_load(arg(1));
}
if (!empty($node)) :
   foreach ($node->field_image_slider['und'] as $item) {
        $val=$item['uri'];
        print '<div class="item"><figure><img src="' .file_create_url($val). '" /></figure><h3 class="orange">Hi</h3></div>';
    } 
endif;
```

Comment: Try updated version ^^. If no luck add `print var_dump($node);` before the `if (!empty`

Comment: I tried printing var_dump($node) before the if , but no luck
thank you alot

Comment: This code is only viewing last added content, for example I added 3 contents of type slider (banner1,banner2,banner3) ; this only displays banner3 . @Scott Anderson

Answer (score 0):

```
print_r($node->field_image_slider); 
die('dead');
```

Let's start from this. Please tell me do you see anything except dead on white screen?

Comment: the page is broken when using these 2 lines.

Comment: That is right as we call die to stop everything, bt as before it we have print_r, then it will output it for easier viewing, for example what I see when use it http://take.ms/VcHid, and values are here, do you see your values? if not then it's empty, try to print_r a whole node and see the result.
Page where you are checking contains node at all?

Comment: print_r($node->>field_image_slider); is printing only the last added content : Array ( [und] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [fid] => 4 [uid] => 1 [filename] => b3.jpg [uri] => public://uploads/b3.jpg [filemime] => image/jpeg [filesize] => 117762 [status] => 1 [timestamp] => 1437641150 [rdf_mapping] => Array ( ) [alt] => [title] => [width] => 768 [height] => 454 ) ) )


this is the array of banner3  ; but I've added banner2 and banner1 before it !

Comment: When I am doing print_r of any multiple field I receive all of them by default, so do you use some workbench moderation module? maybe you haven't published this multiple values, do you have any preprocess to manage this field ? maybe on those stage other values are removed.

Comment: no I don't have any preprocess to manage them ; I don't know how to use them .
The problem is somtimes the $node becomes empty!! Even if there is multiple fields !

Comment: $node could be empty if you a looking not on a node page, for example on views page, can I look on your site somewhere?

Comment: I'm looking in page.tpl.php ; not on node.tpl.php
I'm sorry but the site isn't published yet , is there a standard code for displaying all fields of a content in drupal ?
Or any code that when I add pictures in drupal can display them programatically inside a page.tpl.php

Comment: add to page.tpl.php `render(field_view_field('node', $node, 'field_image_slider'));`

and create new template field--field_image_slider.tpl.php which contains:

`<?php if (!$label_hidden): ?>
  <div class="field-label"<?php print $title_attributes; ?>><?php print $label ?>:&nbsp;</div>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php foreach ($items as $delta => $item): ?><div class="item"><figure>
  <?php print render($item); ?></figure><h3 class="orange">Hi</h3></div>
<?php endforeach; ?>`

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: node in include() (line 78 of C:\wamp\www\drupal\sites\all\Themes\fruition\templates\page.tpl.php).

Comment: Then it means that you are looking not on page with the node, what is url without path alias? if you are on page with node then should be http://yourdomain/node/any_number ?

Answer (score 0):

Use entity_metadata_wrapper:

```
if (!empty($node)) {
    $wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);
    $images = $wrapper-> field_image_slider->value();
    print(var_dump($images));
    ...
}
```

You should get a nice array that is easy to use, empty if there are no images.

Comment: Call to undefined function entity_metadata_wrapper() in C:\wamp\www\drupal\sites\all\Themes\fruition\templates\page.tpl.php on line 417

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that to use the entity_metadata_wrapper() function, you need to install and enable the "Entity API" module (https://www.drupal.org/project/entity).